# Reading data from a serialport from different threads

Tags: c#, asynchronous, serial-port

Using [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application) I created two classes used to read a device on a serial port. The device is a laser which I can control (turn system/lasers on/off, read stats etc.) using commands like SYST:STAT?. Most of the commands immediately send back a response that I can read using the _serialPort.ReadLine().

However, the command SYST:STAT ON that turns on the system is one of the commands that takes about ten seconds. This is where the makers of the laser decided it's nice to send back a message that says: system ready. I can read this response asynchonously using the NewSerialDataRecieved event. In here, I read every line like this:

```
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
{
    _dataReceived += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);

    // Loop as long as there's full lines available
    while (_dataReceived.Length > 0 && _dataReceived.Contains("\r\n"))
    {
        int delimiterIndex = _dataReceived.IndexOf("\r\n", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 2;
        string line = _dataReceived.Substring(0, delimiterIndex); // Get first line from data
        _dataReceived = _dataReceived.Substring(delimiterIndex, _dataReceived.Length - line.Length); // Remove first line from data
        line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 2);

        TryParseSystemReadyResponse(line);
        TryParseEnteringStandbyModeResponse(line);
        TryParseTemperatureResponse(line);

        OnResponseReceived?.Invoke(line);
    }
}
```

The method reads the incoming data, stores it, and then parses the data line by line. This works perfectly for my asynchronous, well defined responses. Here's the catch: most of the responses are formatted like '0 0' or '0 1'. This means there's no way to parse them like that. This is why I read them directly after sending my command to the serial device, like this:

```
public void UpdateLaserState()
{
    // Get the selected laser
    _serialPortManager.SendCommand("LSR:NSEL?");
    int selectedLaser = _serialPortManager.ReadIntegerResponse();
    // Do stuff with the laser number
    OnSystemStateChange?.Invoke();
}
```

ReadIntegerResponse is a method that does a ReadLine, strips the response of the preceding '0 ' and then parses the remaining string to int. Up to now, communication works as well as I would expect. Messages that can be synchronous are being read instantly and asynchronous messages can be parsed by my OnDataReceived method.

Here comes the problem. I need to read the temperature of the laser system about twice a second. My solution was to create a thread that reads the temperature, like this:

```
public Laser(){
    _temperatureThread = new Thread(TemperatureTask);
    _temperatureThread.Start();
    _temperatureThreadRunning = true;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _temperatureThreadRunning = false;
    _temperatureThread.Join();
}

private void TemperatureTask()
{
    while (_temperatureThreadRunning)
    {
        this.UpdateTemperatures();
        Thread.Sleep(TemperatureTaskSleep);
    }
}

public void UpdateTemperatures()
{
    _serialPortManager.SendCommand("SYST:TEMP?");
    //string line = _serialPortManager.ReadResponse();
    //TryParseTemperatureResponse(line);
}
```

This gives problems as UpdateTemperatures sends responses very often on a different thread. I resolved a lot of problems by implementing a lock. However, my responses often get mixed up. I think the following is happening:

```
Main thread            Temperature thread
-----------------------------------------
Sends command       |
                    |  Sends command
Reads response      | 
                    |  Reads response
```

This means the threads are reading eachothers responses. There is no good way to identify responses like '0 0' as belonging to a certain command.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

P.S. the ReadResponse methods of the _serialPortManager all look like this (except for parsing the response):

```
public string ReadResponse()
{
    string response = SafeReadLine();
    return StripResponse(response);
}

private string SafeReadLine()
{
    lock (_serialPortLock)
    {
        string response = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        return StripResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about implement in SerialPortManager a SendReadCommand(string command) then do an lock - call SendCommand(command) - call ReadREsponse - return the response. Further implement the lock to the ReadResponse method. If the class laser needs an TempUpdate it calls SendReadCommand and if the main thread is calling ReadResponse, the thread will be set to idle till SendReadCommand have read the response.

Comment: @user1519979 That sounds like it's really simple and like it should work. Let me get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: for addition the object for locking should be defined somewhere as an single-instance or defined as static. Both classes have to access the same object or it won't work :)